# ASP.NET Cache - What's the difference between direct assignments and Add() or Insert()

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I'm trying to understand the difference between these two items and what one (if any) is the "correct" way to do it.

I'd like to add an object to a cache. For example:

```
List<String> list = new List<String>();
list.Add("Monday");
list.Add("Tuesday");
list.Add("Wednesday");
list.Add("Thursday");
```

Now add the list to the cache. Do I do:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("DaysOfTheWeek", list);
```

Or can I just do this?

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache["DaysOfTheWeek"] = list;
```

I've done both, and they work fine. I'm wondering if this will blow up as this scales, or if it will have any consequences I'm not foreseeing.

This is in C#, ASP.NET 4.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference. Using the indexer (the second example) just calls `Insert` anyway. You can see that in the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Cache/cache.cs,249):

```
    public object this[string key] {
        get {
            return Get(key);
        }

        set {
            Insert(key, value);
        }
    }
```

`Add` is different from `Insert` in that `Add` will not overwrite a value in cache if the key already exists - `Insert` will replace an already cached value. This is mentioned in the [documentation of `Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.add(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Calls to this method will fail if an item with the same key parameter is already stored in the Cache. To overwrite an existing Cache item using the same key parameter, use the Insert method.

Comment: Wow thanks for the reference source! This is really handy!